# C# light-up button on mouse hover

Tags: c#, winforms, button, hover

You know when you add a button in winForms, and then debug, on mouse over the button light`s up. I guess that a hover effect. I want to do the same thing to a pictureBox. How can i do it?

One thing i want this is becouse i added a picture box and imported a .png image of a button. And i am trying to make my own personalized buttons. Is there any smarter/other way to make a button?

Comment: What else are you trying to do with the custom button? You could also create your own Button that inherits from Button.

Comment: Can you post some code on how to do that ?

Comment: You create a new class, and where you name the class, you do something like: `public class CustomButton : Button`. Other than that, you'll have to give a lot more information on what you're trying to do. My first recommendation would be to do a search for custom buttons, and see what other people have done already. I know there are plenty on this site already.

Answer (score 1):

You can hook into the MouseHover event on the Control object to do this.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.mousehover.aspx